# nginx wordpress subdirectory Invalid post type

Tags: nginx

I have an Ubuntu server running Nginx, php-fpm, and wordpress in a subdirectory. My config looks like this:

```
server {
    #My site configuration
    location /blog {
            root /home/user/www;
            index index.php index.html index.htm;
            error_log       /var/log/blog_error.log;
            error_page 404 /blog/404.html;
            error_page 500 502 503 504 /blog/50x.html;
            location /blog/ {
                    try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php?$args;
            }
            location = /blog/favicon.ico { log_not_found off; access_log off; }
            location = /blog/robots.txt { allow all; log_not_found off; access_log off; }
            location ~ /blog/\. { deny all; }
            location ~* /blog/(?:uploads|files)/.*\.php$ { deny all; }
            rewrite /blog/wp-admin$ $scheme://$host$uri/ permanent;
            if (!-e $request_filename) {
                    rewrite ^(.*)$ /blog/index.php?q=$1 last;
                    break;
            }
            location ~ \.php$ {
                    #try_files $uri =404;
                    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(/blog)(/.*)$;
                    fastcgi_index blog/index.php;
                    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                    include fastcgi_params;
                    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            }
            location ~* ^.+\.(css|js|ogg|ogv|svg|svgz|eot|otf|woff|mp4|ttf|rss|atom|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|ppt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf)$ {
                    access_log off; log_not_found off; expires max;
            }
    }
}
```

With a fresh WP installation version 3.7.1, I get `Invalid post type` when I click on the Posts link in my dashboard.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oExqD.png]

And when I click on Add New Post I get the new post page but the right sidebar which should contain the Post button and other controls shows empty.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kPEfs.png]

I'm sure it has got to do something with my configuration, because I'm trying with a fresh DB and a fresh WP.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: What plugins did you install?

Comment: No plugins at all, fresh installation.

Comment: I know of no reason why your nginx configuration should cause these problems, and I don't see any serious problems in it. The cause of these problems almost certainly lies elsewhere.

Comment: I tried a subdomain configuration instead of a subdirectory and it worked flawlessly, the same WP and DB, no changes, only to nginx! This is driving me crazy.

Comment: Wait a minute, are you trying to run multisite _in_ a subdirectory? I don't think you can do that.

Comment: No no, just one blog one site one DB one WP, if I switch it to subdomain it works, if I make it a subfolder I get this stupid error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was solved by commenting out this line

```
fastcgi_split_path_info ^(/blog)(/.*)$;
```

It solved the issue, with apparently no side effects. I got the answer on [Wordpress.org forums](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/nginx-subdirectory-invalid-post-type) which was originally posted on [nginx forums](http://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,229298,230201#msg-230201)

Cheers.